# How can I get the user-friendly label for the available permissions?

Tags: soql, permissions, permission-sets

While I'm able to query the `PermissionSet` object and retrieve `FIELDS(ALL)`, parsing the fields that start with `Permissions` to see which permissions are available, I'd like to get the user-friendly label for these permissions. For example, a simple query can tell me that there's a "View Roles" permission available, but the SF UI shows this as "View Roles and Role Hierarchy." Is there any way to know that that label applies to the `PermissionsViewRoles` field?